# Example of a metric space where triangle inequality doesn't hold?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Give an example of a space where all the conditions of usual metric space are satisfied except the triangle inequality? I [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Semimetrics) such spaces are called semimetrics but I couldn't find any examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(X,d)$, $X = \mathbb{R}$, $d(x,y) = |x - y|^2$

$d(0,n) = n^2 > n = d(0,1) + d(1,2) + \dots + d(n-1,n)$

Answer (score 2):

Draw a triangle with vertices $A,B,C$ and assign three positive numbers  $a,b,c>0$ to its edges:
$$a = d(B,C) = d(C,B), \qquad b = d(A,C) = d(C,A), \qquad c=d(A,B)=d(B,A)
$$
and, of course,
$$d(A,A)=d(B,B)=d(C,C)=0
$$
Now pick the values of those three numbers so that $a \not\le b+c$, or $b \not\le c+a$, or $c \not\le a+b$. For example, $a=3$, $b=1$, $c=1$.

You can think of this as the universal example: given a set $X$ and a function $d : X \times X \to [0,\infty)$ satisfying the first two axioms of a metric, $d$ *fails* to be a metric if and only if there exist three points $A,B,C \in X$ such that the restricted function
$$d \mid \{A,B,C\} \times \{A,B,C\} \to [0,\infty)
$$
is constructed as above.